# Where do I find a Dwarven Armor Fragment?

Tags: the-witcher-2

So I failed the Little Sisters quest in Chapter 2/Roche's Path and looted a diagram for the Mahakaman Sihil steel sword. Amongst others the sword requires a dwarven armor fragment, but I don't have the faintest idea where I could get one. Maybe somebody knows?

Comment: I think crafting is a mess in this game. Dwarven armor fragments are rare, it's only used in one diagram. 

Have you tried any of the chests in houses at Vergen, or seeing if you can get a it as a random drop from the ravine?

Comment: Yeah I've opened all the chests I could access in Vergen, killed some Temerian bandits and monsters (though I don't think they drop anything besides their own body parts, mutagens, trophies and the like) but didn't find anything. Besides, when you travel to Vergen to retrieve the Dun Banner you are awarded the Dun sword which is nearly as good as the Mahakaman Sihil so that crafting the latter becomes a bit pointless at that point.

Comment: It's very hard to get it since it is rare random drop around Vergen - after 5 months people can't even tell what monsters can drop it.

Answer (score 1):

I found something like that in deeper Google. [**Source**.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997903-the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/62648888)

> You can fight **three bullvores** in **Ch 2**, I think. One is summoned, one is in the camp caves, **the third is in the dwarven mines**. I think you get the **fragment from the third**.

Somebody can try this?

Comment: nope... third one doesn't drop it... tried it for at least 20 times...
in the mines there are two bullvores, and any of them is dropping it... I have tried to find the piece in the game (actually I have done the complete game several times both paths for Iorwth and for Roche and never find that piece)...